# Weak*-topology and weak* convergence in Goldstine Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

According to Goldstine Theorem, the unit ball of $c_0(\mathbb N)$ is weak star dense in the unit ball of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. If $f$ would be in the unit ball of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, what  net in the unit ball of $c_0(\mathbb N)$ can be given that converges to $f$?

Can we give the net $\{e_i\}$?

Comment: For $f\in \ell^\infty(\Bbb N)$ let $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x≤n\\ 0 & x>n\end{cases}$. $f_n$ clearly has finite support so its in $c_0(\Bbb N)$. What can you say about any weak* limits it admits?

Comment: We know the dual of $\ell_1$ is dense in $ \ell_\infty$. So, we consider the inner product of the difference $ f- f_n$ and $x$ that $x \in \ell_{1}$. When $ n$ tends to infinity this inner product equals 0. That's true?